# Running rsync in background

Tags: linux, background, rsync

I use this to run rsync in background

```
rsync -avh /home/abc/abac /backups/ddd &
```

When i do that i see line saying 1 process stopped.

Now does that mean my process is still running ot it is stopped

Comment: My one question is: why use -vh if you're running it as a background process; or: why run it as a background process if you want the output?  I'm not criticising, I'm wondering at the context.

Comment: i used that command from command line but now i want to do that in background. i just copied that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is probably trying to read from the terminal (to ask you for a password, perhaps).  When a background process tries to read from the terminal, it gets stopped.

You can make the error go away by redirecting stdin from /dev/null:

```
rsync -avh /home/abc/abac /backups/ddd < /dev/null &
```

...but then it will probably fail because it will not be able to read whatever it was trying to read.

Comment: how can i supply the password in background

Comment: Possibly you could use `echo tHepAssw0rd | rsync -a /home/abc/abac /backups/ddd &` but then anyone doing a ps could see the password.  Are you sure it's a password it wants, and does it have to be a background process?

Comment: i tried that and it still asks for password and when i enter that it says stopped

Comment: @Matty That might not work, since most programs like to read the password from the TTY (not stdin).  @bidu The usual solution is to set up password-less login.  You can do this with minimal security using rsh (via .rhosts) and with decent security using ssh (via authorized_keys, ssh-agent, etc.)

Comment: @bidu Bottom line is that background processes cannot read from the terminal.  It is probably not rsync, but rather the shell (ssh by default, I think) that is prompting for the password.  I suggest learning about password-less ssh logins.

Comment: @Nemo i find it strange that there is no way to pass text to tty. My job was long and it coul take 16 hrs to complete so thats why i wanted in background. now i have started in foreground then put back in background

Comment: @Nemo i tried quitting terminal and when i came back my background job was gone. how can i keep it running when i quit terminal

Comment: @bidu - Try running it under "nohup".  As in `nohup rsync ...`.

Answer (score 33):

When you press "ctrl + z" then the process stopped and go to background.

> [1]+  Stopped rsync -ar --partial /home/webup/ /mnt/backup/

Now press "bg" and will start in background the previous process you stopped.

> [1]+ rsync -ar --partial /home/webup/ /mnt/backup/ &

Press "jobs" to see the process is running

> [1]+  Running rsync -ar --partial /home/webup/ /mnt/backup/ &

If you want to to go in foreground press "fg 1" 1 is the process number

Comment: But how to fg a bg'ed job after relogin with ssh if job running on a remote machine?

Comment: `CTRL+Z` combined with `bg` after remote login works fine for me. Nonetheless, I miss an option to give to rsync, that automates that behaviour: Stay in the foreground for login, then `fork()` and perform the actual transfers in the child, while the parent exits and thus returns control to the calling shell.

Answer (score 29):

## The solution to keep rsync running in background

```
nohup rsync -a host.origin:/path/data destiny.host:/path/ &
```

**Nohup** allows to run a process/command or shell script to continue working in the background even if you close the terminal session.

In our example, we also added ‘&’ at the end, that helps to send the process to background.

#### Output example:

```
 nohup rsync -avp root@61.0.172.109:/root/backup/uploads/ . &

 [1] 33376
 nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'
```

That’s all, now your rsync process will run in the background, no matter what happens it will be there unless you kill the process from command line, but it will not be interrupted if you close your linux terminal, or if you logout from the server.

## RSync Status

```
cat nohup.out
```

Comment: If arg is a remote file/dir, prefix it with a colon (:).

Answer (score 2):

No, it means it has been stopped.

You can check it with `jobs`.

Example output:

```
jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 yes
```

Then you can reactivate with `fg`, example:

```
fg 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is safe, you can monitor nohup.out to see the progress.

```
nohup rsync -avrt --exclude 'i386*' --exclude 'debug' rsync://mirrors.kernel.org/centos/6/os . &
```

Answer (score 0):

If everything works, your call should return you the PID of the new progress and some time later a "Done" message.

So yeah, your output looks like your process is not running.

Check ps to see if rsync is running.

Answer (score 0):

File Transfer:

```
nohup scp oracle@<your_ip>:/backup_location/backup/file.txt . > nohup.out 2>&1 &
```

then hit ctrl-z

```
$ bg
```

To bring the command alive